# if $f$ is function of 2 variables what does notation $f_x$ mean

Tags: notation

if $f$ is function of two variable $x$ and $y$: $f(x,y)$, what do notations $f_x$ or $f_y$ mean? From the derivation I expect it is a partial derivatives $f_x=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, but I'm not sure. Is it correct?

Comment: Yep, you got it

Comment: @PrinceM thanks, does $f_{xx}$ means second partial derivative?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function $f$ on some variables $x_1,\cdots,x_n$, the notation

$$f_{x_{i_1}\cdots x_{i_m}}$$

denotes

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{i_m}} \cdots \frac{\partial }{\partial x_{i_1}} f,$$

where $i_1,\cdots,i_m$ are indices. Specifically,

$$f_x = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f,$$

and

$$f_{xx} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f_x = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} f.$$